# Notification/Widget on lock screen with button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have an app that contains stopwatch and when time is running and the app enters background I would like to have a notification on lock screen and in Notification Center (when you swipe down). The notification should contain actual time of the stopwatches and user should be able to stop/start the stopwatches.

I was trying to achieve this using UNNotificationContentExtension but as documentation says:

> When an iOS device receives a notification containing an alert, the system displays the contents of the alert in two stages. Initially, it displays an abbreviated banner with the title, subtitle, and two to four lines of body text from the notification. If the user presses the abbreviated banner, iOS displays the full notification interface, including any notification-related actions. The system provides the interface for the abbreviated banner, but you can customize the full interface using a notification content app extension.

I found out that I am able to edit just **full notification interface** which means that when user gets notification and opens it I can show him whatever I want (I tried mediaPlayPauseButtonType to handle stopwatches). But when I check the lockscreen the notification stays default.

What are the possibilities to achieve Notification similar to Spotify - when you play song, you can pause the song and you can see the time etc. from the lockscreen?
Thanks!

Comment: Spotify isn't using a notification. They are using the "now playing" controller from the media player framework.

Comment: Is it possible to use this framework for my case? For stopwatch?

Comment: No, it is for music playback https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter

Comment: Is there a way to achieve something like what I described? What could I use?